# What is the difference between a regular Linear Regression model and xgboost with objective set to "reg:linear"?

Tags: linear-regression, xgboost

As I understand it, a regular linear regression model already minimizes for squared error, which means that it is the theoretical best prediction for this metric.  Does xgboost's "reg:linear" objective do something other than minimize squared error?

Comment: Please search before you ask https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232852/is-regression-objective-in-xgboost-invariant-to-feature-attributes-scaling

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already answered here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232852/is-regression-objective-in-xgboost-invariant-to-feature-attributes-scaling

Comment: I'm not sure what feature attribute scaling has to do with my question.  After reading the answers to that question anyway, I still fail to see if there is any difference between a regular linear regression model and xgboost's "reg:linear" objective.

Comment: Boosting is conceptually different to OLS. So your question can be answered „no, not the same thing“. Have a look at Ch 10. https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf  Squared loss is simply an objective function. It is used for many problems

Comment: Does this mean that xgboost with "reg:linear" objective will always underperform a non-xgboost linear regression?

Comment: The idea of boosting is to do better than OLS. Does not always work, but often. OLS is unbiased. Boosting increases bias but reduces variance. Just try on your own. BTW: Catboost or LightGBM are good alternatives to xgboost.

Comment: @Peter, in the ML sense, linear regression is high bias and low variance, and boosted trees low bias and high variance. I think "OLS is unbiased" is referring to the statistical setting of estimating the parameters: the coefficient estimates are _unbiased_ in that the average over all possible samples are the "correct" ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linear regression is a parametric model: it assumes the target variable can be expressed as a linear combination of the independent variables (plus error). Gradient boosted trees are nonparametric: they will approximate any* function.

Xgboost deprecated the objective `reg:linear` [precisely because of this confusion](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3929). It has been replaced by `reg:squarederror`, and has always meant minimizing the squared error, just as in linear regression.

So xgboost will generally fit training data much better than linear regression, but that also means it is prone to overfitting, and it is less easily interpreted. Either one may end up being better, depending on your data and your needs.